# How to write MongoDB query in core PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I have created query in mongoDB. In MongoChef this query produces more than 10 thousand records in less than 2 seconds. Now I want to execute this query in PHP. 
So i don't know how to write query in php as I read various documents on internet but confused how to implement it.

```
 db.PMS.aggregate(
 [
    {$project:
       {EventTS:1,MainsPower:1,PanelID:1}
    },
    {$unwind: 
        {path:"$MainsPower",includeArrayIndex:"arrayIndex",preserveNullAndEmptyArrays:true}
    },
    { $match: { "MainsPower":{$ne:null}}},
    { $match: { "EventTS":{$gt:new Date("2016-01-01")}}},
    {$project:
        {MainsPower:1,
          PanelID:1,
          timestamp:{"$add":
                [{'$subtract' : ["$EventTS",new Date("1970-01-01")]},
                {"$multiply":[60000,"$arrayIndex"]}
                ]}
          }
    }
    ]
);
```

Comment: Which *driver* are you using? Did you read this? http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php

Comment: @m02ph3u5 I am using mongodb version : 1.1.7

Answer (score 1):

You can use some resources available on the php official documentation. A mapping of sql queries in php to mongoDB queries in php can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.sqltomongo.php). 
 Also I have a demo login and registration script at my github. You can view those in [this](https://github.com/ps011/php-mongodb) repo.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [MongoDB PHP Library](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-php-library/?jmp=docs) you should be able to do something similar to this:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient();

$database = $mongo->examples;
$collection = $database->PMS;

$pipeline = [
    [
        '$project' => [
            'EventTS' => 1,
            'MainsPower'   => 1,
            'PanelID'   => 1,
        ]
    ],
    [
        '$unwind' => [
            'path' => '$MainsPower',
            'includeArrayIndex' => 'arrayIndex',
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays' => true

        ]
    ],
    ...
];

$cursor = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Comment: In $match i have to pass dynamic date so how to pass dynamic date variable in pipeline